# How can 'system monitor' can be turned into as powerful as Task manager of Windows in Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, system-monitor

When I use heavy software sometimes my computer gets hanged. I have shut down my laptop holding the power key. Is it possible to open system monitor by keyboard shortcut like what we do in windows by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>?

I am trying to mean that, even in hanged stated if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> the task manager appears and from there I can stop problematic programs successfully. But the system monitor is not that powerful in ubuntu. When ubuntu gets hanged I have no other option to restart it manually. Even I cannot open terminal by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

I need the **system monitor** or the **terminal** to be that powerful to appear on hanged situation by keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or F2, .. F6), which should get you to a TTY.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open an app with a custom keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540633/how-can-i-open-an-app-with-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of something for Linux that is as mighty as Window's Task Manager.

Try `htop`, this will most likely do what you are looking for - according to the headline of this post [More information about htop on wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop)

You can simply install htop via Ubuntu's Software Center.

Once htop is installed, start the terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter `htop` in the terminal.

htop is a very powerful tool for managing and monitoring processes on your Linux.

Comment: What is `strg`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant `CTRL` not `STRG`. The latter is the German equivalent for the English `CTRL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to System Settings->Keyboard you can set up shortcuts manually on one of the tabs (don't have my laptop in front of me to tell you exactly what the tab is called).